# Automatic Scaling when the image is resize

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am having a problem when I change the size of the image. Then the proportions of the line no longer match those of the image, i.e. the line will become smaller than expected.

Any idea how I can resize the line proportionally equal to the image?

Here is the original image:

[image: image (original)]

Here is the result that I want:

[image: image (wanted result)]

But this is the result that I get after resizing (it gives the same value at second picture):

[image: image (result)]

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2


# Method to find the mid point
def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)


img = cv2.imread('banana4.jpg')

# Gaussian blur
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),1)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([5, 25, 25])
upper_blue = np.array([70, 255, 255])
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

# Find contours and sort for largest contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)


for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")

    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    orig = img.copy()

    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
    (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
    (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

    (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)

    (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)

    # draw and write the midpoints on the image
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.putText(orig, "({},{})".format(tltrX, tltrY), (int(tltrX - 50), int(tltrY - 10) - 20),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 2)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY-90)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.putText(orig, "({},{})".format(blbrX, blbrY-90), (int(blbrX - 50), int(blbrY - 10) - 20),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 2)

    # draw lines between the midpoints
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY-90)),
             (255, 0, 255), 2)

    # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
    dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
    dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))

    cv2.imshow("Image", orig) 

    break
```

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you think it makes sense that if you scale the image, you need to scale the line as well? How do you think you would do that?

Comment: I have changed the wording a bit to better describe the problem. I hope I've achieved it. Also I included the images and indented the code (less spaces to the left).

Comment: Let's say for example when I resize my image , the end point will stay at same place but the result will change .

Comment: Why not resize the image first then do your processing to determine the line

Comment: Ya, im done resizing that but when i resize the below starting point will not stay.